# Getting error Component returned failure code: 0x80600001 firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, xslt, cross-browser

// I am perfectly having my XML DOM as source variable
Previously my page is only supporting internet Explorer which is absolutely working fine , but now needed to support firefox and chrome also for that done the necessary changes.

Came to know that transformNodeToObject works with IE only not with other browsers. Searched in diff blogs come to know needed to import XSL stylesheet and use transformToDocument work with firefox n chrome.So added the same which can be seen in else block, but getting this below error:-

Component returned failure code: 0x80600001 [nsIXSLTProcessor.importStylesheet]
 result.importStylesheet(sortPropertiesXSL);

```
   <html>
  <head>
  <script>
   var properties_xmlDoc = null;
    function loadProperties() 
    { 
        var oXMLContainer = findObject("propertiesXML");
        var sortPropertiesXSL = findObject("sortPropertiesXSL");

        if (properties_xmlDoc == null) 
        {
            properties_xmlDoc = loadXMLFromString(oXMLContainer.value);   
        }
        //for IE
        if(window.ActiveXObject){
          properties_xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject(sortPropertiesXSL, properties_xmlDoc);
        }
        //for other browser
        else {
          var result = new XSLTProcessor();
          result.importStylesheet(sortPropertiesXSL);
          result = result.transformToDocument(properties_xmlDoc);
        }
        findObject("propValueDiv").innerHTML = findObject("propertyValueString").innerHTML;   
    }   

    function findObject(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id); 
        }   
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadProperties()">
<div id="propValueDiv" />
<div id="propertyValueString"  style="display:none">
   <textarea name="propertyValue" id="propertyValue"</textarea>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

here is my xsl :-

```
<xml id="sortPropertiesXSL" style="display:none;">
    <xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements="name description value"/>
      <xsl:template match="properties">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates>
             <xsl:sort data-type="text" select="name"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
</xml>
```

can some one tell me why exactly this problem is throwing by ff and how to solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to embedd XML (which XSLT is) inside of an HTML document. That was supported in older IE versions as so called XML data islands but other browsers never supported that and that way your XSLT code embedded in HTML is parsed as HTML in Firefox and not as XML. Put the XSLT in a file of its own which you load with XMLHttpRequest, that way it is parsed as XML.